# return type of access to bitfield

Tags: c++, bit-fields

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct C
{
    uint32_t x : 2;
    bool y : 2;
};

int main()
{
    C c{0b1};

    std::cout << (static_cast<uint32_t>(0b1) << 31) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (c.x << 31) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (c.x << 10) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same_v<decltype(c.x), uint32_t> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same_v<decltype(c.y), bool> << std::endl;
}
```

**Compile**

```
g++ -g  test.cpp -std=c++17
```

`g++ (GCC) 8.2.0`

**Output**

```
2147483648
-2147483648
1024
true
true
```

My question here is regarding the type of the expression `c.x` where `x` is a 2bit bitfield member. According to the typetraits check I got the same type as was declared in the class definition, however it seems that this is not true at runtime since when I try to set the last bit through shifting I get a negative number. Any ideas?

Comment: `c.x` is implicitly converted to `int` inside `c.x << 31` expression.

Comment: why? is that required by the standard? Moreover what is the significance of the type declared in the class definition then?

Comment: See [`[conv.prom]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom)

Comment: Why do you check `std::is_same_v<decltype(c.x), uint32_t>` when you are interested in `std::is_same_v<decltype(c.x << 31), uint32_t>`? `std::is_same_v<decltype(c.x << 31), int>` is true. https://ideone.com/3DTqpl

Comment: if the type of `c.x` is indeed `uint32_t` why should you expect the `operator<<` to change it?

Comment: @mkmostafa: The type is a bitfield. And to be honest, having a "32 bits 2 bits" member is just confusing.

Comment: if you change it from `: 2` to `: 30` you get the same behavior, there is nothing confusing about that. What I find confusing is that an expression with a static type `uint32_t` is being treated as `int` for **built-in arithmetic operators** meanwhile if you add to the previous example `void f(int){}` and `void f(uint32_t){}` and call `f(c.x)`, the second overload gets chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [C++draft 2019-04-12 conv.prom 7.3.6p5](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom):

> 7.3.6 Integral promotions
>
> A prvalue for an integral bit-field ([class.bit]) can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all the values of the bit-field;

From [C++draft 2019-04-12 expr.shift 7.6.7p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift):

> 7.6.7 Shift operators
>
> The shift operators << and >> group left-to-right.
> ...
> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed.

The `typeid(c.x)` is `uint32_t`, however when using `<<` operator, it is implicitly converted to `int`.

`c.x` is `0x1`. The expression `c.x << 31` is `0x1 << 31` is `0x80000000` (assuming `sizoef(int) == 4` and `CHAR_BIT == 8`). This number is interpreted as an `int` and in [twos complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) format it is equal to `-2147483648` (`INT_MIN` or that `std::intergral_limits<int>::min()`).

Note that the expression `c.x << 31` currently (C++17) invokes undefined behavior because of signed integer overflow.

> Moreover what is the significance of the type declared in the class definition then?

Padding. Some compilers interpret different types of bitfields as "padding separators" (don't know how to name it). If the next member in the struct has a different type then the previous one (both being a bitfield), then I would expect the compiler to place the second member starting from a new "fresh" byte. I would expect `c.x` and `c.y` to have bits padding between them, as they have different type. If it would be `struct C { uint32_t y : 2; uint32_t x : 2; }` then it would be more likely for the compiler to put them inside the same byte. Refer to your compiler documentation or [other resources](http://jkz.wtf/bit-field-packing-in-gcc-and-clang).

Comment: It's better to name the paragraph than give its numbering as the later changes with C++ versions.